# Keep A Variable Private But Still Use It In A Function

Tags: powershell

I have a NuGet repo and I wanted to avoid having to go where I store my API key, copy it, go back into Powershell, and then paste it. I decided I was going to store my key in a variable so I could just pass -NuGetAPIKey $NuGetAPIKey to Publish-Module instead of the entire key.

I didn't want to have my API key defined in plaintext right in my profile.ps1, nor did I want to have a text file with it in plaintext either, so I defined a variable $NuGetAPIKey that takes an encrypted version of my API Key, turned it into a secure string, and then decrypts it using PSCredential.

My problem with this, however, and it may just be a necessary evil, if you type $NuGetAPIKey, Get-Variable, or any other function that returns the variable, the API is right there in front of the user.

Is there a way to hide this but still keep it usable by the Publish-Module function? Obviously, if I make the variable private, the function can't read it so that's out of the question.

Here is the line in my profile.ps1 that does the magic:

```
Set-Variable -Name "NuGetAPIKey" -Value (Get-Content 'U:\My Documents\NuGet\APIKey' | ConvertTo-SecureString | ForEach-Object{(New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'N/A', $_).GetNetworkCredential().Password})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the password in an encrypted file 
    $credPath   = 'C:\temp\somesecret.txt'
    $credential = Get-Credential 'Api Key'

```
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $credPath
```

And then you can read the password out. I've showed how to get the secret in cleartext, but you probably want to keep it as a secure string

```
$somesortofsecret = Get-Content $credPath | ConvertTo-SecureString

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'api', $somesortofsecret
$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: I'm beyond this point. I believe that the -NuGetAPIKey option in the Publish-Module cmdlet requires the API key to be entered in plaintext because initially I tried to supply it a secure string and it errored out. If I could store it as a secure string, I would have no need to even be asking this question but unfortunately, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Cameron, I think you misundertand my solution that I provided. I am saying that you would store it as a secure string, but then you can read it back out as a secure string, convert it to a credential, and then you can get the plain text api key by using `$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` to pass into Publish-Module

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a public function that wraps around `Publish-Module` and making `$NuGetAPIKey` private. This way, you can hide the Key and no one else can access it, but they still have access to the `Publish-Module` call.

Something like

```
Function Publish-Module{
    param($path, $nugetapikey, $credential, $formatversion)
}
```

and so on with the parameters (you can also add in the required and types and default values if you want. You can then check if the `$NuGetApikey` is empty or null and assign it the key if it is.

Comment: If it's a private variable, doesn't it have to be defined within the scope of the function to be usable? Right now, the variable is defined right in my profile.ps1, so it's global. If I set the variable to private and then called it in the wrapper function, it wouldn't be able to read it, would it?

Comment: @CameronRatliff I thought you were wrapping it some sort of private class function or module which would load the encrypted string and perform the decryption.